# PrimeFaces spinner mis rendered at the first time!

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Inside a `h:form` I use 3 `p:spinner` components. But they are wrongly rendered at the first time. After the ajax update at form( `ajax render="@form"` ) the up and down arrows are becoming visible.

Help to find the problem. Thank you.

At the First time:
[image: Partially rendered] 
After ajax update at form level:
[image: Fully rendered]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's related to [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?can=1&q=1533&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Module%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20TargetVersion%20Reporter%20Owner%20Summary&id=1533). There is a bug that spinners can't be placed inside initially hidden containers like `p:dialog`.

Comment: p:tooltip also not working if it is not set as global="true". May that also be related to this problem?

Comment: Don't know. But is your container initially hidden?

Comment: Yes it is initially hidden. After a select event is triggered in another combobox, then only it is rendered according to that selection.

Comment: As to the primefaces bug tracking this issue will be fixed in version 3.0.

Comment: Yes I saw that Matt thank you. I m going to use global tooltips and ajaxically rendered Spinners as for now.